# How to mapreduce on key from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Say I have a collection of users like this:-

```
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "Name" : "John",
  "OS" : "5.1",
  "Groups" : [{
      "_id" : "A",
      "Name" : "Group A"
    }, {
      "_id" : "C",
      "Name" : "Group C"
    }]
}
```

And I have a collection of events like this:-

```
{
  "_id" : "15342",
  "Event" : "VIEW",
  "UserId" : "1234"
}
```

I'm able to use mapreduce to work out the count of events per user as I can just emit the "UserId" and count off of that, however what I want to do now is count events by group.

If I had a "Groups" array in my event document then this would be easy, however I don't and this is only an example, the actual application of this is much more complicated and I don't want to replicate all that data into the event document.

I've see an example at http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/ but I can't see how that applies in this situation as it is aggregating values from two places... all I really want to do is perform a lookup.

In SQL I would simply JOIN my flattened UserGroup table to the event table and just GROUP BY UserGroup.GroupName

I'd be happy with multiple passes of mapreduce... first pass to count by UserId into something like { "_id" : "1234", "count" : 9 } but I get stuck on next pass... how to include the group id

Some potential approaches I've considered:-

- Include group info in the event document (not feasible)
- Work out how to "join" the user collection or look-up the users groups from within the map function so I can emit the group id's as well (don't know how to do this)
- Work out how to "join" the event and user collections into a third collection I can run mapreduce over

What is possible and what are the benefits/issues with each approach?

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question with the link to merging the Map/Reduce output.  Whether you are trying to aggregate a value from two collections or do a lookup in another collection, you are still after the equivalent of a join :).  So looks like your best approach is the third one you suggested (M/R merging into a new collection).

Comment: @Aleks, why is my answer not acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third approach is the way to go:

> Work out how to "join" the event and user collections into a third collection I can run mapreduce over

To do this you'll need to create a new collection `J` with the "joined" data you need for map-reduce. There are several strategies you can use for this:

1. Update your application to insert/update `J` in the normal course of business. This is best in the case where you need to run MR very frequently and with up-to-date data. It can add substantially to code complexity. From an implementation standpoint, you can do this either directly (by writing to `J`) or indirectly (by writing changes to a log collection `L` and then applying the "new" changes to `J`). If you choose the log collection approach you'll need a strategy for determining what's changed. There are two common ones: high-watermark (based on `_id` or a timestamp) and using the log collection as a queue with the [`findAndModify`](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6914054) command.
2. Create/update `J` in batch mode. This is the way to go in the case of high-performance systems where the multiple updates from the above strategy would affect performance. This is also the way to go if you do not need to run the MR very frequently and/or you do not have to guarantee up-to-the-second data accuracy.

If you go with (2) you will have to iterate over documents in the collections you need to join--as you've figured out, Mongo map-reduce won't help you here. There are many possible ways to do this:

1. If you don't have many documents and if they are small, you can iterate outside of the DB with a direct connection to the DB.
2. If you cannot do (1) you can iterate inside the DB using `db.eval()`. If the number of documents in not small, make sure to use `nolock: true` as `db.eval` is blocking by default. This is typically the strategy I choose as I tend to deal with very large document sets and I cannot afford to move them over the network.
3. If you cannot do (1) and do not want to do (2) you can clone the collections to another node with a temporary DB. Mongo has a convenient [cloneCollection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/cloneCollection+Command) command for this. Note that this does not work if the DB requires authentication (don't ask why; it's a strange 10gen design choice). In that case you can use `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. Once you have the data local to a new DB you can party on it as you see fit. Once you complete the MR you can update the result collection in your production DB. I use this strategy for one-off map-reduce operations with heavy pre-processing so as to not load the production replica sets.

Good luck!